# Given $X \in \mathbb{R}$ and $Y\in \{0,1\}$, is there a simple expression for $\dfrac{1}{1+e^{-(X+Y)}}- \dfrac{1}{1+e^{-X}}$?

Tags: functions

Suppose $X \in \mathbb{R}$ and $Y\in \{0,1\}$. I am wondering if there exists a simple expression for the following difference in sigmoid functions

$$
\dfrac{1}{1+e^{-(X+Y)}}- \dfrac{1}{1+e^{-X}}
$$

such that I can either separate out the $X$ and $Y$ or solely express it in terms of $Y$?

Comment: Well, this expression is $0$ when $y=0$, so why not $ (\frac 1 {1 + e^{-x - 1}} - \frac 1 {1 + e^{-x}}) y$?

Comment: Do you want to solve $\Delta=\dfrac{1}{1+e^{-(X+Y)}}- \dfrac{1}{1+e^{-X}}$ for $X$ or $Y$ for a given value of  $\Delta$ ?